# Text colour of action bar is not getting changed

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am trying to change the text colour of action bar. I am able to change the background colour but the text colour is not getting changed. I am changing it to white but still is is coming as default black.

Here is my style xml :

```
<resources>

  <style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#000000</item>

    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

Kindly help me where i am wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to set `textStyle`

```
 <style name="AppTheme.ActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">

 <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTitleTextStyle</item>

 </style>
```

and create `MyTitleTextStyle`

```
<style name="MyTitleTextStyle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/wheat</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">21sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

and at last

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
<item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar</item>
<item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
<item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyTitleTextStyle</item>
</style>
```